# How to escape initial json data in jade?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I use nodeJS/express as the backend and jade as a template engine. My Javascript part required some variables from the server. Generally, this can be done like this:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var user = !{JSON.stringify(userObject)};
```

All works fine except the case when `userObject` has `<script>[some text]</script>` block. Please don't ask why this block appears in `userObject` because this is an internal thing and I just want to handle this case.

Because of the fact that the Javascript parser executes earlier than the HTML parser my embedding gets broken with the error:

```
<script>
   var user = {
      name: 'Erik',
      about: '<script>about me</script>'
   };
</script>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

The error happens due to the `about me</script>` line because it closes the main `<script>` tag.

So my question is: what is proper way to handle this error?

Comment: When we have similar problems (apostrophes also cause breaks in this case), we write an API call to get the data we need and call it with node's $http or using ajax in a script tag.

Comment: I don't like idea to get initial data with additional request. What if it fails?

Comment: If you use the exact same function on the same server you are serving your website from, it seems unlikely that it will fail in any cases where it wasn't going to already fail.

Comment: It will. `<script>about me</script>` string could be in any place

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an endpoint and do a GET request to it for the data, there are two more crude solutions. Note that these are kludgey hacks. I still think the best way to solve this is with an AJAX request to an API endpoint with the required data within the `<script>` tag.

1) Have functions that strip out the `<` and `>` characters and apply them before and after.

E.g. In the Express endpoint:

```
function replaceTags(aboutSection) {
    aboutSection = aboutSection.replace(/</g, '%StartBracket%');
    aboutSection = aboutSection.replace(/>/g, '%CloseBracket%');
    return aboutSection;
}
```

In the client side code:

```
function undoReplace(aboutSection) {
    aboutSection = aboutSection.replace(/%StartBracket%/g, '<');
    aboutSection = aboutSection.replace(/%CloseBracket%/g, '>');
    return aboutSection;
}
```

I'm using regex with the `g` tag to make sure everything, not just the first instance, is replaced.

2) If you don't need the about section, you could delete it before passing it to the endpoint.